# Please reopen question so that I can move the answer from the question body

Tags: support, reopen-closed

[What is the memory overhead of opening a file on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309852/what-is-the-memory-overhead-of-opening-a-file-on-windows)

A few users deemed it "too broad".

Since I have measured the answer myself, I would like to add the answer (already provided in the question text) to a proper answer.

Comment: Sounds fair to me, added my vote. :)

Comment: 5th vote in....